# Can I use vue-router to data-bind a dropdown's value to a URL's query parameter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-router4

I want to bind a dropdown to a query parameter in the URL, so

- when opening `/page?dropdown=foo`, I want the dropdown to have `foo` pre-selected
- and the other way round: when changing the dropdown's value to `bar`, to have the URL rewritten into `/page?dropdown=bar`.

My question now:
Is there an out-of-the-box way to tell vue-router to data-bind this?

Or do I need to do it by hand, so when entering/changing the route, setting the dropdown's value and using a `:onchange` on the dropdown to call `router.replace()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't bind it in the way you are thinking, but for sure there is a manner to achieve that.

On router config, it's possible to set `props` as `true`, which means that the `route.params` will be set as the component props, so `dropdown` will be set with the value on URL (`foo` or `bar`).

Make your component react to changes on prop `dropdown`, this can solve your first question.

For the second question, I think your approach is correct, using the `replace` method, which would change the URL, and navigate to it but without adding a new history entry, just replacing it.